# How keep same table cell highlighted after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have html table and when users clicks any cell that cell gets highlighted with yellow color! However if i refresh the page the the selected cell is no longer highlighted with yellow color! Could any one show me how to re highlight previously selected table cell after refresh using local storage method. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .selected_link {background:yellow;}

</style>

<script>

var myGlobalScrollPosition=0;

function RestoreSelectedTableCell()
{

ScrollPositionVariable = localStorage.getItem("ScrollPosition2");
window.scrollTo(0,ScrollPositionVariable);

};

</script>

<script language="javascript">
    function hide_selection(){
        var lnks = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
        for(i=0; i<lnks.length; i++){
            if (lnks[i].className == "selected_link"){
                lnks[i].className = "";
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    function selectLink(ob){
               //alert("value of ob:"+ob);
        hide_selection();
        ob.className = "selected_link";
    }
</script>
<script>
function MyFunction(var1,var2,var3)
{
     alert("var1:"+var1+" var2:"+var2+" var3:"+var3);


myGlobalScrollPosition = document.body.scrollTop;

//saving scrollpostion on html5 localstroage
localStorage.setItem("ScrollPosition2", myGlobalScrollPosition);
};
</script>
</head>

<body onload="RestoreSelectedTableCell()">

<div id="myDiv" style="display: visiable;"> 

<table id="demoajax" style="display: visible;" class="inlineTable" border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item#</th>
      <th>Logo</th>
      <th>Title</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  <tr id="1">
<td>1</td>
<td><img src="./apple.png" height="42" width="42"></td>
<td>
<a id="fruits" href="javascript:MyFunction('fruits','2','./apple.png')" onclick="selectLink(this);">Apple
</a><br><br>
</td>
</tr>

<tr id="2">
<td>2</td>
<td><img src="./mango.png" height="42" width="42"></td>
<td>
<a id="fruits" href="javascript:MyFunction('fruits','4','./mango.png')" onclick="selectLink(this);">Mango
</a><br><br>
</td>
</tr>

<tr id="3">
<td>3</td>
<td><img src="./orange.png" height="42" width="42"></td>
<td>
<a id="fruits" href="javascript:MyFunction('fuits','7','./orange.png')" onclick="selectLink(this);">orange
</a><br><br>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>test<br>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your html code

```
 <div id="myDiv" style="display: visiable;">

  <table id="demoajax" style="display: visible;" class="inlineTable" border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Item#</th>
        <th>Logo</th>
        <th>Title</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr id="1">
        <td>1</td>
        <td><img src="./apple.png" height="42" width="42"></td>
        <td>
          <a id="one" href="javascript:MyFunction('fruits','2','./apple.png')" onclick="selectLink(this.id)">Apple
</a>
          <br>
          <br>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="2">
        <td>2</td>
        <td><img src="./mango.png" height="42" width="42"></td>
        <td>
          <a id="two" href="javascript:MyFunction('fruits','4','./mango.png')" onclick="selectLink(this.id)">Mango
</a>
          <br>
          <br>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="3">
        <td>3</td>
        <td><img src="./orange.png" height="42" width="42"></td>
        <td>
          <a id="three" href="javascript:MyFunction('fuits','7','./orange.png')" onclick="selectLink(this.id)">orange
</a>
          <br>
          <br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

javascript file

```
var selected = [];
storedSelected = [];
$(function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("selected") != null) {
    storedSelected = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selected"));
        selected = storedSelected;
    storedSelected.forEach(function(ele) {
      console.log(ele);
      $('#' + ele).addClass("selected_link");
    });
  }
});




var myGlobalScrollPosition = 0;

function RestoreSelectedTableCell() {

  ScrollPositionVariable = localStorage.getItem("ScrollPosition2");
  window.scrollTo(0, ScrollPositionVariable);

};



function selectLink(ob) {
  console.log(ob)
  if (jQuery.inArray(ob, selected) !== -1) {
    var index = selected.indexOf(ob);
    if (index > -1) {
      selected.splice(index, 1);
    }
    $('#' + ob).removeClass("selected_link");

  } else {
    selected.push(ob);
    $('#' + ob).addClass("selected_link");
  }
  console.log(selected);

  localStorage.setItem("selected", JSON.stringify(selected));
  console.log("storeage:" + localStorage.getItem("selected"));
}

function MyFunction(var1, var2, var3) {
  alert("var1:" + var1 + " var2:" + var2 + " var3:" + var3);


  myGlobalScrollPosition = document.body.scrollTop;

  //saving scrollpostion on html5 localstroage
  localStorage.setItem("ScrollPosition2", myGlobalScrollPosition);
};
```

and 
[see this code in Jsfiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/gahc2rqh/)

Comment: Thanks for reply.May i know why you used array for ob instead of global variable?i would appreciate if you show me a demo on jsfiddle.